# How to extend columns when export COLUMNS doesn't work

Tags: bash, terminal, gnu-screen, columns

**UPDATE: it appears to be related to GNU `screen` and `termcap`: see new clues at bottom.**

---

I'm running Bash 4.3 on a small embeddable device, and having a problem convincing it that I have more than 80 columns in my terminal.

If I type a command that goes past 80 columns, instead of continuing (the best case) or wrapping to the next line (acceptable but not ideal) it begins putting new characters on the same line that I'm typing on.

If I run

```
set | grep COLUMNS
```

I see `COLUMNS=80`.  But if I try to increase this

```
export COLUMNS=200
```

there is no change in behavior.

The prescription mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219547/how-do-i-get-more-than-80-columns-in-command-line-mode) of using `shopt -s checkwinsize` did not help.

Various details that could *possibly* be relevant:

- The computer I'm connecting *from* is OS X 10.11.6.
- My terminal is iTerm2 (Build 3.1.beta.4).
- I've been opening a new terminal window each time to ensure fresh terminal settings.
- the embeddable device is a C.H.I.P. Pro.
- The C.H.I.P. Pro is running Debian:
  `Linux chip 4.4.30-pro #1 SMP Wed Dec 21 01:50:18 UTC 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux`
- Bash is 4.3.30, compiled for ARM (of course):
  `GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf)`
- I'm using GNU screen to connect to the C.H.I.P. Pro.
- I've disabled my `~/.screenrc` to get default settings.
- The output of `shopt` is:

  ```
  autocd          off
  cdable_vars     off
  cdspell         off
  checkhash       off
  checkjobs       off
  checkwinsize    on
  cmdhist         on
  compat31        off
  compat32        off
  compat40        off
  compat41        off
  compat42        off
  complete_fullquote      on
  direxpand       off
  dirspell        off
  dotglob         off
  execfail        off
  expand_aliases  on
  extdebug        off
  extglob         off
  extquote        on
  failglob        off
  force_fignore   on
  globstar        off
  globasciiranges off
  gnu_errfmt      off
  histappend      on
  histreedit      off
  histverify      off
  hostcomplete    on
  huponexit       off
  interactive_comments    on
  lastpipe        off
  lithist         off
  login_shell     on
  mailwarn        off
  no_empty_cmd_completion off
  nocaseglob      off
  nocasematch     off
  nullglob        off
  progcomp        on
  promptvars      on
  restricted_shell        off
  shift_verbose   off
  sourcepath      on
  xpg_echo        off
  ```

---

***UPDATES:***

1. I just discovered that using `screen`'s width command (C-a W) gives me the message "Your termcap does not specify how to change the terminal's width to 132."
2. However, using `width 300`, `width -w 300`, and `width -d 300` don't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `resize`: it updates the `stty` settings (which is what's lost by connecting directly to the embedded device — and also what's needed by `screen`).

[**`resize`**](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/resize.html) is a command-line utility (developed with **`xterm`**), which checks for the actual screen-size (using VT100 escape-sequences) and updates `stty` to reflect that size as well as printing commands which can be executed to update environment variables.

Changing `$COLUMNS` within `screen` is not very effective, since `screen` "knows" how large the terminal screen is, and will interfere with programs that assume a different size.

Comment: I was *just* looking at that command, but it appears to deal only with height of panes: https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Resize.html .  I'm not splitting my window into different panes, and I'm having a problem only with the width.  If I'm making some false assumptions or interpretations of the documentation, could you give an example of how to use resize to expand the width?